# How do I choose JavaScript for my AppleScript SCPT file?

Tags: javascript, applescript, osascript

I'm calling an Applescript scpt file and when I opened the AppleScript editor it had an option to use JavaScript.

I would like to convert my AppleScript to JavaScript but can't find any documentation on it (announcements and such and redirects on apple).

Here is my AppleScript:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv

    set output to "{\"1st Parameter\":\"" & first item of argv & "\"}"
    return output

end run
```

**More context:**

I'm trying to loop through a directory and export from Excel. I only need to know about how to run JavaScript in a SCPT file but this is the background.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv

    #goal is to export multiple files to csv
    #the plan is to
    #pass in folder and loop through files or 
    #pass in array of files (paths as a comma separated string)
    #pass in single file and call script multiple times
    set processReportsScript to "excel -e '" & first item of argv & "'  '" -o '" & second item of argv & "'.csv'"

    do shell script processReportsScript

end run
```

**UPDATE:**

While in **Script Editor** I'm able to run this **JavaScript**:

```
function run(args) {
  var x = false;
  var y = Application("Mail");
  var running = y.running();
  var id = y.id();

  debugger;

  if (x) { 
    console.log("Why isn't this being called?")
  }

  return "hello";
}
```

Based in part on this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-11.html).

However when I save the JavaScript into the SCPT file and call it from an external application it gives the following error:

> script error: Expected end of line, etc. but found “(”. (-2741)

It does not give any errors when using AppleScript.

FYI the external application is passing the script to **osascript**.

**UPDATE 2:**

I changed the extension from scpt to js and now it's running. I read that it's possible to pass in the language type using -l but when I do I get numerous variations of the error:

> no such component " 'JavaScript'"
>   no such component " JavaScript"

As long as it works by changing the extension I think this works.

Comment: The `function` runs fine for me as `.scpt` when passed directly to `osascript`. What is the external app that's passing it to `osascript`? BTW From the man page "-l language
           Override the language for any plain text files.  Normally, plain
           text files are compiled as AppleScript."

Comment: That's interesting. I might be passing argument incorrectly but if it works for you without changing anything then I'm not sure. It's an Adobe AIR app using a native process call. I passed the argument `-l JavaScript` and `-l "JavaScript"` and `-l "javascript"` and variations of it.

Comment: I don't have Adobe AIR, so I can test, sorry.  The `-l` option is only for plain text files, not `.scpt` when the language is other then AppleScript. (Read the man page for osascript.)

Comment: That's OK. I think I have it mostly working.

Answer (score 1):

Both AppleScript and JavaScript for Automation (JXA) use the same file extension:  ".scpt".  When you are in the Script Editor, there is a language popup where you can select either:

[image]

The is no tool for auto-conversion from AppleScript to JXA.

For more info about JXA, see
[JXA Resources](https://apple-dev.groups.io/g/jxa/wiki/JXA-Resources)